# How to ask user for contacts app permission in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

I am building a contacts app in Flutter. I am using permission_handler to ask user for Contacts permission. I want to achieve one of the two targets:

1. The app keeps on asking the user for permission until granted.
2. When the user opens the app for first time, ask for permission. For subsequent launches if permission is not already granted, show an error message and exit the app.

I tried the following code and used it in initState() function.

```
Future<bool> _requestContactsPermission() async {
    //If permission is already granted return immediately
    if (await Permission.contacts.isGranted) return true;

    //Check if the app is running first time
    bool firstRun = await IsFirstRun.isFirstRun();
    if (firstRun) {
      PermissionStatus result = await Permission.contacts.request();
      return result.isGranted;
    }

    showToast('You have disabled a required permission.');
    return false;
  }
```

But the app stops immediately. I have included the following lines in Android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```